# UnityEngine.SystemLanguage does not contain Hindi language

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I need to install the SDK in a project that has a localization for the HIndi language inside itself. The problem is that the systemLanguage on my PC does not contain this language. It is available on other PCs and this language is specified in the documentation. I can't figure out what the problem is and where he got lost.

I've tried different projects, different versions of Unity. There is no Hindi language anywhere. This language is present on other PCs.